# If 2 out of 3 maps between short exact sequences is zero, is the third also zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

In this commutative diagram, suppose that the rows are short exact sequences of modules over a commutative ring:

$$
0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0 
$$

$$ f\downarrow \qquad\downarrow g \quad \downarrow h $$

$$0 \longrightarrow D \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow F \longrightarrow 0 
$$

Suppose that $f=0$ and $h=0$. Does this imply that the middle map $g=0$ ?

Answer (score 6):

Take $\require{AMScd}$ a non-zero module $M$ and consider
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> 0 @>>> M @>1>> M @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @V0VV @V1VV @V0VV @VVV \\
0 @>>> M @>1>> M @>>> 0 @>>> 0
\end{CD}